# plant id - purple flowers, tall stalk, grass like, beige spore

Tags: identification

What is this plant? It has purple flowers and very pretty. I don't think it is weed, just because of the spots in the backyard where I find this plant.

- purple flowers, about 2" in diameter
- About 3 ft tall
- grass-like, has tall stacks
- beige spores that appeared within the last week, as big as a baseball or perhaps bigger

[image: purple flower]
[image: beige spore]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classed as a wildflower, its Salsify, or Tragopogon porrifolius, a biennial plant with edible roots http://www.jeremybartlett.co.uk/2012/05/29/salsify-tragopogon-porrifolius/